# Qual è il senso di "sconfinare" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Non doveva essere uno scemo puro: è piú probabile che appartenesse a quel tipo umano di cui si dice in Piemonte che fanno i folli per non pagare il sale: al riparo dietro l’immunità che si concede ai deboli di mente, Bortolasso esercitava con negligenza estrema la funzione di giardiniere. Con una negligenza tale da **sconfinare** in un’astuzia rudimentale: sta bene, il mondo lo aveva dichiarato irresponsabile, ed ora doveva sopportarlo come tale, anzi mantenerlo ed avere cura di lui.

Ho cercato il verbo "sconfinare" su parecchi dizionari, ma le diverse accezioni riportate non sembrano avere senso nel contesto di questo brano.

Unicamente sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI18/00175.jpg) ho trovato all'accezione numero 4:

> Mutarsi in un sentimento analogo ma più intenso.

Tuttavia, in questo caso non si tratta di sentimenti.

Il significato sarebbe che la negligenza di questo personaggio poteva quasi considerarsi un’astuzia rudimentale? O che non era del tutto chiaro se l'atteggiamento di questo personaggio fosse negligenza o un'astuzia rudimentale? Oppure che il modo in cui questo personaggio era negligente assomigliava molto a un'astuzia rudimentale? O qualcosa di questo genere?

Comment: Qualsiasi cosa può "sconfinare". Inoltre, "sconfinare" e "sconfinato" possono significare cose molto diverse.

Comment: Questo è il senso: ***sconfinare*** figurato Uscire dai limiti proposti o fissati per un argomento: *sconfiniamo dal tema principale, dall’oggetto della discussione; anche assol.: atteniamoci al tema, non sconfiniamo.* (treccani.it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sconfinare** viene utilizzato in questo caso nel senso di *uscire dai confini, dai limiti*, ma in modo metaforico.

La negligenza del personaggio era tale da uscire dai limiti entro cui poteva essere considerata negligenza vera e propria (quindi in qualche misura involontaria) e si trasformava in qualcos'altro: un vero e proprio stile di vita, perseguito con coscienza: il mondo lo ha etichettato come irresponsabile, e lui lo fa apposta ad esserlo.